# When deployed, HTML content inside a {{ #with }} is not displayed

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a meteor code that works just fine when running localhost, but when I deploy it in Google Cloud, almost everything works, except one of my pages that contains a form, and that form I pre-populate with data coming from the server.

This is my HTML:

```
<template name="ConfigForm">
  {{ #with configurationData }}
  <form class="update-config">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Email Recipients</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label for="decimal" class="sr-only">Email Recipients</label>
        <input type="text" id="send_to_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Recipients" autofocus value="{{ send_to_email }}">
      </div>
    </div>
....
```

Then, my javascript file for this particular page has:

```
Template.ConfigForm.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
  Meteor.call('getConfig',function(err,response) {
    if(err) {
      console.error('Error')
      return;
    }
    Session.set('config', response);
  });
});
Template.ConfigForm.helpers({
   configurationData: function() {
     return Session.get('config')
   }
});
```

And, finally, my server has the `Meteor.methods` defined that return the config JSON object used to populate the form. As I mentioned, it works just fine in localhost.

When I open the deployed webpage and check the Chrome console, this is what I see:

[image: Google Chrome Console errors]

So that makes me thing it could be some issue with my deployment configuration, more specifically regarding sticky sessions. But not really sure, and also not sure what I could change in my deployment script to fix that.

And, lastly, my Dockerfile for the GCloud deployment is:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs
RUN install_node v4.8.2
COPY . /app/
RUN (cd programs/server && npm install --unsafe-perm)
CMD node main.js
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**
Adding the getConfig method as requested:

```
Meteor.methods({
        getConfig: function() {
          return {
            btcmBTCFee:btcm_btc_fee,
            btcmBTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            indyBTCFee:indy_btc_fee,
            indyBTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            coinjarBTCFee:coinjar_btc_fee,
            coinjarBTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            coinspotBTCFee:coinspot_btc_fee,
            coinspotBTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            russelBTCFee:coinspot_russel_btc_fee,
            russelBTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            acxBTCFee:acx_btc_fee,
            acxBTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            btcmLTCFee:btcm_ltc_fee,
            btcmLTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            indyLTCFee:indy_ltc_fee,
            indyLTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            coinspotLTCFee:coinspot_ltc_fee,
            coinspotLTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            russellLTCFee:coinspot_russel_ltc_fee,
            russellLTCTransferFee:transfer_fee,
            minimum_pct_for_alert:minimum_pct_for_alert,
            minimum_variation_pct_to_send_alert:minimum_variation_pct_to_send_alert,
            enable_send_alert:enable_send_alert,
            send_to_email:send_to_email
          };
        }
    });
```

It is an extremely simple function, it is just returning global variables. I am not even reading from MongoDB just yet.

**EDIT2:**

I actually forgot I have the app.yml file, the ROOT_URL is there, and also correct:

```
entrypoint: meteor run
env: flex
runtime: custom
env_variables:
  ROOT_URL: https://<<url>>.appspot.com/
  MONGO_URL: "mongodb://<<user>>:<<pw>>@ds157444.mlab.com:57444/arbot"
  DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS: "1"
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?\.dockerignore$
- ^(.*/)?\npm-debug.log$
- ^(.*/)?\yarn-error.log$
- ^(.*/)?\.git$
- ^(.*/)?\.hg$
- ^(.*/)?\.svn$
```

**SOLUTION:**

I got it to work!
I decided to change `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS: "1"` to `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS: "0"` and tada!! working!! :)

Comment: Show your `getConfig` method as well

Comment: Also, seems like your `ROOT_URL` env var is unset.

Comment: @Styx - I have added the function description as per request. Where do I set the ROOT_URL?

Comment: @FelipeCaldas you should not include the answer as part of the question.  Add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I got it to work! I decided to change DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS: "1" to DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS: "0" and tada!! working!! :)